# html5-canvas background doesn't cover entire page

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm currently using a canvas animation as the background of my new portfolio page. It works wonderfully *until* there's more content than can be displayed on a single page, but once you scroll down you'll find the canvas stops at the dimensions of the initial page display even though it's supposed to be the same size as the body element.

I apologize if this is a question that has been answered but I've been looking for a solution all morning and I'm coming up with nothing. Any help you can give is greatly appreciated.

My deployed page can be found [here](https://theamberlamps.github.io/pro_portfolio/), and below is the JS.

Javascript:

```
  var canvas,
    ctx,
    circ,
    nodes,
    mouse,
    SENSITIVITY,
    SIBLINGS_LIMIT,
    DENSITY,
    NODES_QTY,
    ANCHOR_LENGTH,
    MOUSE_RADIUS;

  // how close next node must be to activate connection (in px)
  // shorter distance == better connection (line width)
  SENSITIVITY = 100;
  // note that siblings limit is not 'accurate' as the node can actually have more connections than this value that's because the node accepts sibling nodes with no regard to their current connections this is acceptable because potential fix would not result in significant visual difference
  // more siblings == bigger node
  SIBLINGS_LIMIT = 10;
  // default node margin
  DENSITY = 50;
  // total number of nodes used (incremented after creation)
  NODES_QTY = 0;
  // avoid nodes spreading
  ANCHOR_LENGTH = 20;
  // highlight radius
  MOUSE_RADIUS = 200;

  circ = 2 * Math.PI;
  nodes = [];

  canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  resizeWindow();
  mouse = {
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: canvas.height / 2
  };
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  if (!ctx) {
    alert("Ooops! Your browser does not support canvas :'(");
  }

  function Node(x, y) {
    this.anchorX = x;
    this.anchorY = y;
    this.x = Math.random() * (x - (x - ANCHOR_LENGTH)) + (x - ANCHOR_LENGTH);
    this.y = Math.random() * (y - (y - ANCHOR_LENGTH)) + (y - ANCHOR_LENGTH);
    this.vx = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    this.vy = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    this.energy = Math.random() * 100;
    this.radius = Math.random();
    this.siblings = [];
    this.brightness = 0;
  }

  Node.prototype.drawNode = function() {
    var color = "rgba(216, 48, 168, " + this.brightness + ")";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(
      this.x,
      this.y,
      2 * this.radius + (2 * this.siblings.length) / SIBLINGS_LIMIT,
      0,
      circ
    );
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
  };

  Node.prototype.drawConnections = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.siblings.length; i++) {
      var color = "rgba(24, 168, 216, " + this.brightness + ")";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
      ctx.lineTo(this.siblings[i].x, this.siblings[i].y);
      ctx.lineWidth = 1 - calcDistance(this, this.siblings[i]) / SENSITIVITY;
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  };

  Node.prototype.moveNode = function() {
    this.enbergy -= 2;
    if (this.energy < 1) {
      this.energy = Math.random() * 100;
      if (this.x - this.anchorX < -ANCHOR_LENGTH) {
        this.vx = Math.random() * 2;
      } else if (this.x - this.anchorX > ANCHOR_LENGTH) {
        this.vx = Math.random() * -2;
      } else {
        this.vx = Math.random() * 4 - 2;
      }
      if (this.y - this.anchorY < -ANCHOR_LENGTH) {
        this.vy = Math.random() * 2;
      } else if (this.y - this.anchorY > ANCHOR_LENGTH) {
        this.vy = Math.random() * -2;
      } else {
        this.vy = Math.random() * 4 - 2;
      }
    }
    this.x += (this.vx * this.energy) / 100;
    this.y += (this.vy * this.energy) / 100;
  };

  function initNodes() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    nodes = [];
    for (var i = DENSITY; i < canvas.width; i += DENSITY) {
      for (var j = DENSITY; j < canvas.height; j += DENSITY) {
        nodes.push(new Node(i, j));
        NODES_QTY++;
      }
    }
  }

  function calcDistance(node1, node2) {
    return Math.sqrt(
      Math.pow(node1.x - node2.x, 2) + Math.pow(node1.y - node2.y, 2)
    );
  }

  function findSiblings() {
    var node1, node2, distance;
    for (var i = 0; i < NODES_QTY; i++) {
      node1 = nodes[i];
      node1.siblings = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < NODES_QTY; j++) {
        node2 = nodes[j];
        if (node1 !== node2) {
          distance = calcDistance(node1, node2);
          if (distance < SENSITIVITY) {
            if (node1.siblings.length < SIBLINGS_LIMIT) {
              node1.siblings.push(node2);
            } else {
              var node_sibling_distance = 0;
              var max_distance = 0;
              var s;
              for (var k = 0; k < SIBLINGS_LIMIT; k++) {
                node_sibling_distance = calcDistance(node1, node1.siblings[k]);
                if (node_sibling_distance > max_distance) {
                  max_distance = node_sibling_distance;
                  s = k;
                }
              }
              if (distance < max_distance) {
                node1.siblings.splice(s, 1);
                node1.siblings.push(node2);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function redrawScene() {
    resizeWindow();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    findSiblings();
    var i, node, distance;
    for (i = 0; i < NODES_QTY; i++) {
      node = nodes[i];
      distance = calcDistance(
        {
          x: mouse.x,
          y: mouse.y
        },
        node
      );
      if (distance < MOUSE_RADIUS) {
        node.brightness = 1 - distance / MOUSE_RADIUS;
      } else {
        node.brightness = 0;
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NODES_QTY; i++) {
      node = nodes[i];
      if (node.brightness) {
        node.drawNode();
        node.drawConnections();
      }
      node.moveNode();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(redrawScene);
  }

  function initHandlers() {
    document.addEventListener("resize", resizeWindow, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveHandler, false);
  }

  function resizeWindow() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  }

  function mousemoveHandler(e) {
    mouse.x = e.clientX;
    mouse.y = e.clientY;
  }

  initHandlers();
  initNodes();
  redrawScene();
})();
```

Comment: `canvas.height = window.innerHeight;`, `window.innerHeight` is the viewport's height and not the body's height. So it won't be the same size as the body.

Comment: Ok, so now `canvas.height = document.body.scrollHeight`, which is assigning the full height of the page. However the page still displays exactly as it did before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the canvas `width` property to `document.body.scrollHeight`, that's the full height of the document
2. Set the canvas `height` property to `document.body.clientWidth`, that's the full width of the document minus the scroll bar.
3. Change the height style of the canvas to `fit-content` or remove it. `height: 100%` will make it as high as the viewport.

Comment: That's done it! Thank you so much, this has been vexing me for far too long. :)

Comment: Sure no problem, however it would by nice if you marked my answer as accepted to help others and myself.

Comment: Done and done. :)  Apologies, it's my first post. Certainly not my last though.